# Counting how many confidence intervals

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop, counter

So this is my table in R. For convienence I'll just do 5 replicates.

```
  V1         V2         V3         V4         V5
1 -1.4136084 -1.6883369 -0.9209277 -1.5650176 -1.4695545
2 0.2414484 -0.2508248 -0.1921887 0.1516668 0.3347349
```

How would I be able to count the times the value 0 is in between these other values? confidences[1] < 0 < confidences[2]

This is my code at the moment...

```
> x = 0
> confidences <- replicate(5,t.test(rnorm(n = 10, mean = -0.5, sd = 1))$conf)
> for(i in ncol(confidences)){if(confidences[1] < 0 & 0 < confidences[2]){x+1}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sum(confidences[1,]<0 & confidences[2,]>0)
```

Comment: Thanks! So simple. I sometimes think too complex.